# Exponential of a skew-skymmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a skew-symmetrical matrix with it's diagonal elements as $0$, Prove that it's exponent $e^A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that

$$e^A := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} A^n$$

Since $(A^t)^n = (A^n)^t$ we get that $(e^A)^t = e^{(A^t)}$. Moreoever we will need the following property of the exponent that $e^A\cdot e^B = e^{A+B}$ for any commuting matrices $A,B$.

We are given that $A$ is skew symmetric (i.e. $A^t=-A$). Therefore $A$ and $A^t$ commutes and so $$e^A\cdot (e^A)^t = e^{A+A^t} = e^0 = I$$ where $0$ denotes the zero matrix.

Comment: +1, but your mixed uses of $t$ and $T$ for matrix transpose is confusing.

Comment: @user1551 you're absolutely right thanks.

Comment: Don't you also need to require that $A$ and $B$ commute to have that property of the exponential?

Comment: @JonathanZ I'm not sure, but it sounds like something I need to require, yes. Anyway I edited, but $A$ definitely commutes with $A^t = -A$ so it doesn't change the answer.

Comment: @Yanko: To be honest it's a point that I'm often unsure about and have check frequently. I just know that I can't use it automatically and didn't want the OP to get the idea that it always holds. And if it's not always true that $A$ and $A^t$ commute (which is another thing I'm not immediately sure of) then maybe you could include your comment about them commuting in this case in your answer?